# Python Pandas DataFrame Create Columns with specific value on iteration of every row

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, numpy

Say I have a `pandas` DataFrame as below:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'ID':['B', 'A', 'A', 'C', 'A']})

#   ID
# 0  B
# 1  A
# 2  A
# 3  C
# 4  A
```

And I have the following function:

```py
def func(id):
    # returns a list of three ['columnName', 'value'] pairs (values are random number between 0 and 5)
    # example: [[1,0], [3,4], [0,2]]
    res = [np.random.randint(0,5, size=2) for i in range(3)]
    return res
```

I want to iterate each value in `ID` column, execute `func` on that value (which returns pairs of `['columnName', 'value']`), and then for each pair of values returned by `func`, I need to create a new column and assign the value to that specific row. This is a sample output:

```
  ID    1    3    0    2    4
0  B  3.0  4.0  NaN  3.0  NaN
1  A  0.0  4.0  4.0  NaN  4.0
2  A  1.0  1.0  1.0  0.0  NaN
3  C  1.0  1.0  NaN  NaN  NaN
4  A  1.0  4.0  0.0  2.0  0.0
```

To clarify this, suppose this array was generated by `func` for the first row:

```py
[[1, 3], [3, 4], [2, 3]]
```

As you can see in the sample output, columns with names "1,3,2" were created with values "3,4,3" respectively.

```
  ID    1    3    0    2    4
0  B  3.0  4.0  NaN  3.0  NaN
```

#### What I've done so far:

```py
for id in df['ID']:
    for rowIndex in df.index[df['ID'] == id]:
        for columnName, value in func(id):
            df.loc[rowIndex, columnName] = value
```

This works just fine! **The only problem is that it's not efficient at all**. That's because when I look for rowIndex of specific `ID` (say 'A' for instance), it might be present multiple times in the column and iterates over them all. And later it **overrides** them too. Isn't there any better way to write this?

#### Note:

This is just a simplified version of my project. So `id` is not used by the `func`. Also, `func` doesn't return random values for specific `ID`s and it returns the same value for each `ID`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First idea is working with groups, but necessary reshape by [`Series.unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.unstack.html) before [`DataFrame.join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html):

```
df1 = df.join(df.groupby('ID')['ID'].apply(lambda x: dict(func(x))).unstack(), 'ID')
```

For improve performance working only with unique values in list comprehension before [`DataFrame.join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html):

```
u = df['ID'].unique()
df1 = df.join(pd.DataFrame([dict(func(x)) for x in u], index=u), on='ID')
print (df1)

  ID    4    0    3    1    2
0  B  1.0  4.0  0.0  NaN  NaN
1  A  2.0  NaN  NaN  1.0  NaN
2  A  2.0  NaN  NaN  1.0  NaN
3  C  NaN  2.0  1.0  NaN  0.0
4  A  2.0  NaN  NaN  1.0  NaN
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do `series.map` and create a dataframe of it , then join

```
df.join(pd.DataFrame(df['ID'].map(lambda x: dict(func(x))).tolist()))
```

Sample Run:

```
np.random.seed(0)
def func(id):
    # returns a list of three ['columnName', 'value'] pairs (values are random number between 0 and 5)
    # example: [[1,0], [3,4], [0,2]]
    res = [np.random.randint(0,5, size=2) for i in range(3)]
    return res
print(df.join(pd.DataFrame(df['ID'].map(lambda x: dict(func(x))).tolist())))

  ID    4    3    0    2    1
0  B  0.0  1.0  NaN  NaN  NaN
1  A  0.0  2.0  4.0  NaN  NaN
2  A  NaN  NaN  1.0  1.0  0.0
3  C  NaN  0.0  NaN  NaN  4.0
4  A  NaN  3.0  1.0  3.0  NaN
```